# error: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, deployment, build

In my project, I'm using Angular6 for the frontend. Now what I'm trying to do is deploy my project which is in remote server into the actual server. I'm using `npm run build -prod` command to build the frontend first. But I can't build my project since the following error occurs again and again,

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! Trackit-Revamp@6.0.0 build: `ng build --prod --build-optimizer --aot`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Trackit-Revamp@6.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Indrajith.E\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-22T08_41_00_271Z-debug.log
```

My error log in the `C:\Users\Indrajith.E\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-22T08_41_00_271Z-debug.log` file path contains the same error details mentioned above.

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to this problem without reinstalling npm and I'm posting it because in future it will help someone,
Most of the time this error occurs javascript heap went out of the memory. As the error says itself this is not a problem with npm. Only we have to do is

instead of,

```
npm  run build -prod
```

extend the javascript memory by following,

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
```

Comment: Do we just type this on the terminal? Didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you mean 4096?

Comment: Can you do this kind of thing but in React project ?

Comment: I personally not too familiar with react but I hope so

Answer (score 74):

Delete your `package-lock.json` file and `node_modules` folder. 
Then do npm cache clean

```
npm cache clean --force
```

do 
`npm install`

again and run

Comment: Please can you update the answer I dont want to reinstall npm because I'm working with very large project

Answer (score 9):

I'm on **Ubuntu 18.04**. I fixed this problem by increasing the ***inotify max_user_watches*** using this command:

> echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

Answer (score 9):

Please delete `package-lock.json` and clear npm cache with `npm cache clear --force`
and delete whole `node_modules` directory

Finally install or update packages again with `npm install` / `npm update`
You can also add any new packages with `npm install <package-name>`

This fixed for me.

Thanks and happy coding.

Comment: thanks. your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: Thank you this worked for me. This can  be solution of above error

Answer (score 6):

I'm new with react... Well i had the same output:

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:196
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/public'
    at FSWatcher.<computed> (internal/fs/watchers.js:168:26)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1351:34)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
    at setFsWatchListener (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
    at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
    at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:5)
Emitted 'error' event on FSWatcher instance at:
    at FSWatcher._handleError (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
    at createFsWatchInstance (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
    at setFsWatchListener (/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:165:5) {
  errno: -28,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'ENOSPC',
  path: '/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/public',
  filename: '/opt/lampp/htdocs/react-tuto/public'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-tuto@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-tuto@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/paulo/.npm/_logs/2019-12-16T16_46_27_856Z-debug.log
```

I just tried:

```
sudo npm start
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 5):

I already have the same problem . and I fix it using **npm update** & **npm cache clean --force**

Comment: This is the fix for me to get to work on my local machine. I also had the same error on my Azure DevOps pipeline. we were using "npm run build -- --configuration=prod --base-href=/path/". It worked for all other config params except this prod. So i ended up updating to simply "npm run build -- --prod --base-href=/path/". I hope it may be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 4):

Delete node_modules

```
rm -r node_modules
```

install packages again

```
npm install
```

Comment: removing node modules does not harm our dependencies or further project?

Comment: @SarthakRaval, as you are installing them again in the next steps there will be no harm in it.

Answer (score 4):

Delete node_module directory and run below in command line

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

If still not working, try below

```
npm install webpack --save
```

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was in `firebase.json`, the `site` name was incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

For the people it didn't work, I spent two days finding the solution and there was just one command that worked like a magic.

`npm install -g live-server`

and then run: `npm start`

it will start as normal.You can read all the details here https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server

Answer (score 3):

I had encountered the same `error`. And, I just simply deleted the whole `node_modules` folder, and installed the `npm` packages again solved my `error`.

1. Delete `node_modules` (don't worry you have `package.json`)
2. `npm install`

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the package-lock.json did it for me. I'd suggest you not push package-lock.json to your repo as I wasted hours trying to npm install with the package-lock.json in the folder which gave me helluva errors.

Comment: But reinstalling the whole npm package is not the best practice

Answer (score 2):

Check if port you want to run your app is free. For me, it was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Following steps solves my problem:
 Add "C:\Windows\System32\" to your system path variables 
 Run npm eject, 
 Run npm start,
 Run npm eject,
 and agian run
 npm start
 And it worked

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was trying to install an old version of bcrypt which was not found in npm, I just edited package.json and manually put the latest version and then ran `npm install` and it worked

Answer (score 2):

1. first delete the file (project).
2. then rm -rf  \Users\Indrajith.E\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-22T08_41_00_271Z-debug.log (this is the file(log) which is showing error).
3. recreate your project for example :- npx create-react-app hello_world
4. then cd hello_world.
5. then npm start.

I was also having this same error but hopefully after spending 1 day on this error i have got this solution and it got started perfectly and i also hope this works for you guys also...

Answer (score 1):

Novice mistake. Make sure your package.json file is coded correctly. I had:

```
"start": "index node.js"
instead of:
"start": "node index.js"
```

17

Delete your package-lock.json file and node_modules folder. Then do npm cache clean

npm cache clean --force
do  npm install

Answer (score 1):

I just do two steps:
first:

```
export METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=true;
```

second:

```
sudo systemctl stop bbb-html5
```

and finally:

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 1):

My project is on wagtail. I solved this problem by running the following command:`npm update & npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue in React. In my case it was happening, because I didn't see warnings/errors above the message. After fixing the issues, everything worked properly. Hopefully it's going to help someone.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, I restarted the server and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it happens because of the low version of Node. Upload my Node version and it worked successfully.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32010203)