# can't run : npm start on react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I try to run my project with npm start it does show this error it doesn't seem to be clear for me:

```
react-app-rewired start

The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received undefined
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webapp@0.1.0 start: `react-app-rewired start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kilanh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-03-11T09_43_14_766Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Already solved here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi

Comment: what start command defines in your package json file?

Comment: start": "node ./index.j"

Answer (score 1):

- i faced the same issue I think the problem is with npm with yarn it works fine please try the following :
- delete lock files
- delete node_modules
- run "yarn"
- run "yarn start"

Comment: delete node_modules and the lock files the run
 npm cache clean --force  . 
then npm install .did you try this?

Comment: Yeah it have nothing with npm as I think, it's something related to path as it showed in the error ..