# unable to install and run nodemon npm - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

i am unable to run my nodejs project , getting the below error.

```
> restfullnodejs@1.0.0 start C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs
> nodemon app.js

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! file C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! restfullnodejs@1.0.0 start: `nodemon app.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the restfullnodejs@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-01T13_04_14_121Z-debug.log
```

My guess is the error with nodemon , if so how do i resolve this issue . Unable to install nodemon too

**Update**
After deleting package-lock.json file and nodemodules folder tried `npm clear cache --force` then `npm install - g nodemon`

then getting below error

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! file C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! path C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall: `node bin/postinstall || exit 0`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Users\PC\restfullnodejs\git\bin\bash.exe ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-01T14_10_55_492Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi

Comment: Yes , after trying all those methods still facing same issue. You have a look at my updated question

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue on PC/Windows;

Try:

1. Deleting the package-lock.json, and node_modules folder.
2. Run 'npm install' from the root folder for your app.
3. Run 'npm install -g nodemon'

Comment: @Bush , could u please provide solution to the updated question

Comment: Sure! I would try uninstalling and reinstalling node. But can you post a snippit of your package.js in the meantime? Also, when is this error being thrown? When you running 'npm start ...' or when your using 'npm install ...'

Comment: problem occurs when i run `npm install -g nodeman` then same with `npm start`, i didnt disturb my package.json . `"main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC" `

yup, tried uninstalling and re-installing too same issue still

Comment: did you build them ( npm run build) ?