# React Project keeps throwing weird issues when I restart it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-fullstack

I'm trying to follow along with this fullstack React tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDV3Z1KCBvo&t=2579s&ab_channel=CleverProgrammer

I haven't gotten far because every time I shut down my laptop and open the project again, npm start throws a weird error. I restarted the entire project from scratch because it kept throwing an error about the semver module being messed up. Now it's throwing a similar error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:311
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/jaredb96/Documents/Projects/ReactProjects/amazon-clone/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:303:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:516:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaredb96/Documents/Projects/ReactProjects/amazon-clone/node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js:23:24)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/Users/jaredb96/Documents/Projects/ReactProjects/amazon-clone/node_modules/webpack-manifest-plugin/package.json',
  requestPath: 'webpack-manifest-plugin'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! amazon-clone@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the amazon-clone@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

So this time, the issue isn't semver but webpack. I'm not sure what to do, I've been reinstalling node and npm to no avail. I have another project that I started in a similar way but npm start works flawlessly with it, even after shutting things down.

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "amazon-clone",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How about if you delete the node modules then do npm install again?

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: Just posted it!

Comment: Try adding `"main": "index.js"` as a property to your `package.json` object - I believe that's what the error is telling you to do. A `package.json` initiliased by `npm init` will usually create one by default.

Comment: It may help to delete your package-lock.json and then reinstall — sometimes this gets out of whack and can lead to a bad dependency tree.

Comment: I added "main": "index.js" to the package and it still messes up. I really think it's in the tutorial, I just don't know where

Comment: Zac's suggestion worked! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do was delete my package-lock.json, delete the node_modules, run npm cache clean --force then run npm install. Got part of the solution from the comments, part from here:
[error: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi)