# Application Error - Problem Heroku commit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

```
I am Trying to commit my  Node App to Heroku and i Get Heroku Application Error.
Can someone help me please .
```

I followed A video from Youtube to Upload the project.

```
1. git push heroku master Everything up-to-date  
 
 2. heroku open Opening https://lintim3.herokuapp.com/

 3. heroku restart Restartin  processes... done
```

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command.

Heroku LOGS

heroku logs --tail

```
2021-01-22T23:42:13.269418+00:00 app[web.1]:enter code here npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-01-22T23:42:13.276924+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-22T23:42:13.277129+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-22T23:42:13.277280+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T23_42_13_271Z-debug.log
2021-01-22T23:42:13.324388+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-22T23:42:13.360547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-22T23:42:13.364076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-22T23:42:18.774281+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-01-22T23:42:22.272989+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-01-22T23:42:22.273002+00:00 app[web.1]: > chat@1.0.0 start /app
2021-01-22T23:42:22.273003+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run start-production-server
2021-01-22T23:42:22.273003+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:42:23.069256+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:42:23.069268+00:00 app[web.1]: > chat@1.0.0 start-production-server /app
2021-01-22T23:42:23.069269+00:00 app[web.1]: > pm2 start server/server.js --name dev.socialmedia --watch
2021-01-22T23:42:23.069270+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:42:23.094232+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: pm2: not found
2021-01-22T23:42:23.109410+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-01-22T23:42:23.110342+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-01-22T23:42:23.110846+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-01-22T23:42:23.111312+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-01-22T23:42:23.121190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! chat@1.0.0 start-production-server: `pm2 start server/server.js --name dev.socialmedia --watch`
2021-01-22T23:42:23.121435+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-01-22T23:42:23.121699+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-01-22T23:42:23.121960+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the chat@1.0.0 start-production-server script.
2021-01-22T23:42:23.122190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-01-22T23:42:23.145479+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:42:23.145951+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-22T23:42:23.146271+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T23_42_23_123Z-debug.log
2021-01-22T23:42:23.171905+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-01-22T23:42:23.172569+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-01-22T23:42:23.186798+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! chat@1.0.0 start: `npm run start-production-server`
2021-01-22T23:42:23.187154+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-01-22T23:42:23.187537+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-01-22T23:42:23.187866+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the chat@1.0.0 start script.
2021-01-22T23:42:23.188184+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-01-22T23:42:23.199918+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:42:23.200385+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-22T23:42:23.200698+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T23_42_23_189Z-debug.log
2021-01-22T23:42:23.273146+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-22T23:42:23.326833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-22T23:43:47.358906+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=b56b6f67-f15f-47d3-86d2-29ce4196b3b1 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:43:47.734588+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=533374ab-75af-440c-90af-d8bba074a8e0 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:48:23.802056+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-01-22T23:48:28.564574+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-01-22T23:48:32.180506+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.180530+00:00 app[web.1]: > chat@1.0.0 start /app
2021-01-22T23:48:32.180530+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run start-production-server
2021-01-22T23:48:32.180531+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.872563+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.872622+00:00 app[web.1]: > chat@1.0.0 start-production-server /app
2021-01-22T23:48:32.872623+00:00 app[web.1]: > pm2 start server/server.js --name dev.socialmedia --watch
2021-01-22T23:48:32.872623+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.887354+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: pm2: not found
2021-01-22T23:48:32.901575+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-01-22T23:48:32.902212+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2021-01-22T23:48:32.902768+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2021-01-22T23:48:32.903476+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2021-01-22T23:48:32.914065+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! chat@1.0.0 start-production-server: `pm2 start server/server.js --name dev.socialmedia --watch`
2021-01-22T23:48:32.914366+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2021-01-22T23:48:32.914929+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-01-22T23:48:32.915288+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the chat@1.0.0 start-production-server script.
2021-01-22T23:48:32.915595+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-01-22T23:48:32.930361+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.937000+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.937307+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T23_48_32_917Z-debug.log
2021-01-22T23:48:32.958379+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-01-22T23:48:32.959887+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-01-22T23:48:32.974082+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! chat@1.0.0 start: `npm run start-production-server`
2021-01-22T23:48:32.974422+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-01-22T23:48:32.974789+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-01-22T23:48:32.975090+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the chat@1.0.0 start script.
2021-01-22T23:48:32.975361+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-01-22T23:48:32.983706+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.984907+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-01-22T23:48:32.985218+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-01-22T23_48_32_976Z-debug.log
2021-01-22T23:48:33.089845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-22T23:48:33.163248+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-01-22T23:48:33.638614+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=b9ac3901-5fcb-40f2-8420-0464e8e30f34 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:48:33.799962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=44c43e53-8f8e-4d66-9dcf-44146fc9a18e fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:48:33.961000+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=8fe5133f-cd5d-4ec9-ae82-52fd9f539261 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:48:34.215805+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=604136f0-82cd-40fa-bdc4-ce8df0892566 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:48:34.287166+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=f9e35331-4d75-4a54-9cf8-774562d3b2d9 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:48:35.456617+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=e4f3e1c9-d207-47b9-b20b-214afdb7da1a fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:48:35.692999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=c2e27ca4-4f29-4e09-9555-7a86f522813c fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:24.202241+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate` by user hasanovh14@gmail.com
2021-01-22T23:49:28.884962+00:00 heroku[run.5646]: State changed from starting to up
2021-01-22T23:49:29.050982+00:00 heroku[run.5646]: Awaiting client
2021-01-22T23:49:29.077371+00:00 heroku[run.5646]: Starting process with command `rake db:migrate`
2021-01-22T23:49:33.675679+00:00 heroku[run.5646]: Process exited with status 1
2021-01-22T23:49:33.716695+00:00 heroku[run.5646]: State changed from up to complete
2021-01-22T23:49:38.564580+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=b0978990-9f86-48f2-8107-57a54c40d4ce fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:38.830155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=ba0f42ae-9c27-4936-b2e1-6aca48b4534f fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:39.371118+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=e35012bf-3184-4b99-a567-b5567fc49564 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:39.569871+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=06bb424f-9cd9-4714-a783-ba328919b7a7 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:39.723090+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=a5809903-11a3-40de-858b-dedf2ffee4d3 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:39.930554+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=62aaa41d-93a2-4c1c-a9c0-5a608731e36d fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:40.664719+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=c289b0c2-a25e-4948-896a-96466fb8c671 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:40.869988+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=bc80d13b-6b38-4cb8-a4a9-4e35076c255b fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-01-22T23:49:41.062316+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=lintim3.herokuapp.com request_id=9ea30fe3-095e-4f81-9643-296205110521 fwd="84.165.174.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

on localhost ist working Perfectly

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi seems like an issue with NPM

Comment: i tryied but not working with me .