# React Native Setup

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, command-line-interface

I am new to react native and I am trying to set it up using the tutorial from this youtube video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-S5a0eXPoc&t=811s

However, I am getting errors whenever I try to run the program.

When I run it using expo start I get this error:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:127:28)
```

And when I run it using npm start, i get this:

```
Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (internal/fs/watchers.js:127:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried some solutions from here: [error: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi)

But they did not work.

Comment: How did you create your project?

Comment: if you are planning to use expo to develop your react-native project. I recommend you to follow expo get started documentation. https://docs.expo.io

Comment: @garjted thank you a lot! it worked

Comment: No problem at all.