# Expo server keeps shutting down

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, react-native, expo

I am using Expo SDK 41.0.1 and Node v14.16.1. I recently formatted my computer and now expo server keeps shutting down sporadically with the following error:

```
(node:19580) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\mr-app\.git\objects\maintenance.lock'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ start: `expo start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-04T10_14_15_284Z-debug.log
```

I am also getting the same error on bare react-native projects. I've tried reinstalling node and expo from my computer be it didn't seem to work. Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi)

Comment: This looks like you have a problem with concurrent git maintenance tasks `git/objects/maintenance.lock` is there to prevent multiple of those tasks to run in parallel.
see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-maintenance for more info

Comment: @line-o can you please suggest a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Add `webpack.config.js` to ignore the .git folder

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /.git/,
  },
};
```