# erro:This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above

Tags: vue.js, npm

In my project, I'm using VueCli for the frontend. Now what I'm trying to do is deploy my project which is in remote server into the actual server. I'm using npm run build command to build the frontend first. But I can't build my project since the following error occurs again and again

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mobile-h5@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mobile-h5@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/daisywu/.npm/_logs/2021-09-24T06_13_06_000Z-debug.log
```

I delete `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`,then do `npm cache clean --force`,then do `npm install`,Still unable to construct

debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.9
3 info using node@v14.15.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~prebuild: mobile-h5@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~build: mobile-h5@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~build: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/daisywu/Documents/mobile-h5/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~build: CWD: /Users/daisywu/Documents/mobile-h5
10 silly lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle mobile-h5@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: mobile-h5@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid mobile-h5@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/daisywu/Documents/mobile-h5
16 verbose Darwin 20.3.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v14.15.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.9
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error mobile-h5@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the mobile-h5@0.1.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please help thank you

---

The reason is insufficient memory. Update the answer for your reference

Written in `package.json`
`"build": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build --mode development"`

do `npm run build`

Comment: please share complete log what you are getting in console

Comment: @MaBbKhawaja Debug.log has been added

Comment: try using older version of npm

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57605441/error-this-is-probably-not-a-problem-with-npm-there-is-likely-additional-loggi) help?

Comment: @Mr. I tried it and I can't

Comment: Do not delete lock file for a stable project, this will just ruin it. There are no indications of a possible problem. That it happens during build process which is resource-demanding may mean that the problem is related to hardware, most probably RAM, but could also be CPU architecture (Mac). If the server has less than 3-4gb free RAM this would be a reasonable explanation. Since you provided no details on the server, there's nothing to work with. Try to run build process directly to avoid garbage output from npm, `npx vue-cli-service build`.

Comment: I can improve the memory test. Thanks