# I have an error when building my nodejs app, the error is with vue-cli-service

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I have an error when I try to build my nodejs app with "vue-cli-service".

The error is :

```
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ozu/ui@1.2.3 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ozu/ui@1.2.3 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I use lerna but I don't think it can be the cause of the problem.

I tried to delete the node_modules file the npm install again, I tried to add "error-stack-parser" to my package.json but nothing works and I don't understand where the error come from.

For more details : I'm deploying on Windows, I'm using Lerna to compile multiple packages, so I have 4 package.json, I got the error in the build in one of them, the package.json looks like that :

```
{
  "name": "@ozu/ui",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  "main": "dist/main",
  "types": "dist/main",
  "author": "anonymous_author",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ozu/common": "^0.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "croppie": "^2.6.4",
    "cypress": "^8.3.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.4.1",
    "file-list-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.26.10",
    "tiptap": "^1.27.1",
    "tiptap-extension-superscript": "^0.1.0",
    "tiptap-extensions": "^1.29.1",
    "tiptap-vuetify": "^2.24.0",
    "validatorjs": "^3.17.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.0.2",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-croppie": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-template-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.23.2",
    "vuetify": "^2.1.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "^0.9.8",
    "vuex-persist": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.11.2",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.1.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.12.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "error-stack-parser": "2.0.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^23.0.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^0.5.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.0.5"
  }
}
```

The debug log show this :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'D:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~prebuild: @ozu/ui@1.2.2
6 info lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~build: @ozu/ui@1.2.2
7 verbose lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~build: PATH: D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\ozu\packages\ui\node_modules\.bin;D:\ozu\packages\ui\node_modules\.bin;D:\ozu\packages\node_modules\.bin;D:\ozu\node_modules\.bin;D:\node_modules\.bin;D:\nodejs;D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\ozu\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\oracle\instantclient_19_3;D:\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\Git\cmd;C:\Users\adlj\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
9 verbose lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~build: CWD: D:\ozu\packages\ui
10 silly lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service build' ]
11 silly lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @ozu/ui@1.2.2~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: @ozu/ui@1.2.2 build: `vue-cli-service build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @ozu/ui@1.2.2
15 verbose cwd D:\ozu\packages\ui
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "D:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v12.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ozu/ui@1.2.2 build: `vue-cli-service build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ozu/ui@1.2.2 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: How can I reproduce your issue from scratch?

Comment: It's complicated as I'm working on a already existant project so I don't know how to create it from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exported the output in a file so I could see it in a whole and I saw other errors:

```
> root@1.0.0 build /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu
> lerna run build

lerna notice cli v3.22.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna info Executing command in 3 packages: "npm run build"
lerna info run Ran npm script 'build' in '@ozu/common' in 2.0s:

> @ozu/common@0.0.1 build /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/common
> npm run compile


> @ozu/common@0.0.1 compile /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/common
> tsc -p tsconfig.build.json

lerna info run Ran npm script 'build' in '@ozu/api' in 9.5s:

> @ozu/api@1.0.1 build /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/api
> npm run compile && npm run build:doc


> @ozu/api@1.0.1 compile /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/api
> tsc -p tsconfig.build.json


> @ozu/api@1.0.1 build:doc /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/api
> apidoc -i src/ -o doc

{"level":"warn","message":"Please create an apidoc.json configuration file."}
{"level":"warn","message":"parser plugin 'apiparamexemple' not found in block: 0"}
{"level":"warn","message":"parser plugin 'apiparamexemple' not found in block: 11"}
{"level":"warn","message":"parser plugin 'apiparamexemple' not found in block: 2"}
{"level":"info","message":"Done."}
lerna ERR! npm run build exited 1 in '@ozu/ui'
lerna ERR! npm run build stdout:

> @ozu/ui@1.2.3 build /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui
> vue-cli-service build


Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 12 errors2:27:37 PM

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/partials/EditEventText/editEventText.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/partials/EditEventText/editEventText.ts
24:84 Property 'event' is used before its initialization.
    22 |   @Prop() event: EventModel
    23 |   private error: any = {}
  > 24 |   private newText: EventTextModel = {name: '', value: '', position: 1, event: this.event}
       |                                                                                    ^
    25 |   private createTextMode: boolean = false
    26 |   private currentText: EventTextModel
    27 | 

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/bulletins.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/bulletins.store.ts
120:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    118 |       }
    119 |     } catch (e) {
  > 120 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
        |                                           ^
    121 |       return null
    122 |     }
    123 | 

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
42:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    40 |       }
    41 |     } catch (e) {
  > 42 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
       |                                           ^
    43 |       return null
    44 |     }
    45 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
58:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    56 |       }
    57 |     } catch (e) {
  > 58 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
       |                                           ^
    59 |       return null
    60 |     }
    61 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
74:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    72 |       }
    73 |     } catch (e) {
  > 74 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
       |                                           ^
    75 |       return null
    76 |     }
    77 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
91:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    89 |       }
    90 |     } catch (e) {
  > 91 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
       |                                           ^
    92 |       return null
    93 |     }
    94 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
108:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    106 |       }
    107 |     } catch (e) {
  > 108 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
        |                                           ^
    109 |       return null
    110 |     }
    111 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
125:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    123 |       }
    124 |     } catch (e) {
  > 125 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
        |                                           ^
    126 |       return null
    127 |     }
    128 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
142:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    140 |       }
    141 |     } catch (e) {
  > 142 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
        |                                           ^
    143 |       return null
    144 |     }
    145 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/bulletins/exports.store.ts
161:43 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    159 |       }
    160 |     } catch (e) {
  > 161 |       this.context.commit('_ApiError', (e.message))
        |                                           ^
    162 |       return null
    163 |     }
    164 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/users.store.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/stores/users.store.ts
70:20 Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
    68 |       return {
    69 |         success: false,
  > 70 |         message: e.message
       |                    ^
    71 |       } as ResponseObject
    72 |     }
    73 |   }

 error  in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/views/Bulletin/bulletin.ts

ERROR in /home/dev/Dropbox/CS/projects/ozu/packages/ui/src/views/Bulletin/bulletin.ts
9:23 Cannot find module 'http' or its corresponding type declarations.
     7 | import DeleteDialog from '../../partials/DeleteDialog'
     8 | import { liveApiUrl, liveTestApiUrl, newLiveApiUrl, newLiveTestApiUrl } from '../../conf'
  >  9 | import * as http from 'http'
       |                       ^
    10 | 
    11 | @WithRender
    12 | @Component({


lerna ERR! npm run build stderr:
-  Building for production...
DEPRECATION WARNING: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($border-radius-root, 2) or calc($border-radius-root / 2)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

   ╷
14 │     'sm': $border-radius-root / 2,
   │           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
```

I understood that there was an error with some packages, I updated typescript and vuetify and clean everything and rebuild and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes with Node, you have to use the heavy artillery! You have not given enough details for me to understand this issue so I'm just listing here the lazy-debugger-universal megatool:

```
> yarn (or npm) cache clean --force
> rm -rf ./node_modules
> rm -f yarn-lock.json (and/or package-lock.json and every other lock files)
> yarn (or npm) install
```

Let's know whether the above commands solve anything. But I'd prefer you tell us what was the real issue though when you find it...

Comment: Sadly it doesn't solve anything. What details would you know ? I added some more on my question.

Comment: Thanks for adding some details. Have you found and read some NPM debug logs? If so, please post them. Have you already tried something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57605990/11988016? Give a try to `set NODE_OPTIONS =--max-old-space-size=4096&& vue-cli-service build` to check if it's about memory.

Comment: I added the log error that i got, I tried what you said but it still is the same error